# R. is not giving me an option for array

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android development. I'm trying to have my `string.xml` file add the string instead of hard coding the string in the `.java` file.

I'm using [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) android developer tutorial and copied and pasted the code to make sure there are no typos.

The problem I am having is when I enter `R.array` does not show up as an option. I am not really sure what is wrong. Here is the Java-code. I have put a `//` by the lines that is giving me trouble:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloListActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
        //The R. does not offer array as an option
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries));

        ListView lv =getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View view,
                    int posistion, long id){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)view).getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and here is my `strings.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Bahrain</item>
        <item>Bangladesh</item>
        <item>Barbados</item>
        <item>Belarus</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
        <item>Belize</item>
        <item>Benin</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Deleting the import R worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Project -> Clean` and then Rebuild. The R.java is not holding the resource you just added. EDIT: also make sure to `import YourPackage.ProjectName.R;`

Comment: Thanks, but now .countries_array is not coming up as an option.  I tried clean and then rebuild again and it did not work

Comment: try placing what you have in strings.xml in arrays.xml

Comment: and by the way it's `strings.xml` not `string.xml`. That's why it's not showing nothing.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what file he has declared it in. R will still compile it as an R.array resource.

Comment: Yes but you have `string.xml` instead of `strings.xml` and Android doesn't recognize that.

Comment: I just deleted my strings.xml file, leaving just my string.xml file and android recognized it just fine.

Comment: the file name is strings.xml not string.xml

Comment: Yes, but does R.array.countries_array appear?

Comment: @AaronI'm well aware that the default name is strings.xml, but when android compiles, it, it stores it based on resource id, not the file name. Therefore, it should not matter whether he has declared the file as strings or string, it should show up under R.array in the R file and that is how android will find it. Feel free to test it if you have doubts.

Answer (score 16):

Just closing the project and re-opening it worked for me, array identifier appeared in the
list options.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this issue.  +1 for the old turn it off and back on again.  It worked.

Comment: project clean and rebuild didn't work for me but this answer worked! Kinda weird ...

Comment: The thing that worked for me was just changing JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have built the project. Right click, build (or at the top, Project -> Build All).

It may not know about the array yet since you said you've just copied and pasted and therefore it is not registered as a valid resource.

Comment: The `R.java` file is recreated every time you save a file in your Project (if you're using Eclipse).

Comment: make sure you do not have a phantom android.R at the top (though I suspect you would have a lot more errors than just that). Couldn't hurt to check.

Comment: One more test: under the gen (not the src) folder, open up the R.java. under `public static final class array` does countries_array show up?

Comment: Also: What error are you getting when you leave it as R.array.countries_array?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You always say you put the strings in the `string.xml`-file. The file should be named `strings.xml` (with an "s" -> string **s** .xml).</strike>

It seams that it doesn't madder which name the file is being given, but it needs to be declared as a recourse-file by using the `<resource>`-element as the root-element for the XML-file and the file must be placed in the `res/values`-folder in your Project.

If there is a problem with the recourse-files, the ADB should give an Error-Message telling you what you should fix. In Eclipse, this shows up in the "Console"-View. Check if you get any error-message there.

You could also try to use only `array` instead of `string-array` (this always worked for me).

Comment: Just for clarification, does it matter if it's strings or string? I just tested it out by making a new xml file labeled "asdf.xml", placing a `<string-array name=test>` and I was still able to find it by asking for R.array.test.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't madder (just found it out, too). But you'll have to declare it using the `recourse`-tags and the beginning of the file and the XML-file must be placed in the `res/values`-folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look like:
in `strings.xml` file under `res/values`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="countries_array">
    <item>Bahrain</item>
    <item>Bangladesh</item>
    <item>Barbados</item>
    <item>Belarus</item>
    <item>Belgium</item>
    <item>Belize</item>
    <item>Benin</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access it using R.array.countires_array, it needs to be put in 
    array.xml

Since it's stored in string.xml, it will be located under R.string.countires_array

Comment: This is not the case. Please see the very first part of Lukas Knuth's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `R.id.tv_id` and `this` before `setListAdapter` Try it:

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,  R.id.label, countries));
ListView lv =getListView();
//lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, countries));                                     use this before setListAdapter and id(R.id.label) of TextView  from list_item.xml